# Prerender routes behind authentication

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-snap

I'm currently trying to prerender my routes so that they can be placed on S3 as a static site, without the need to point error pages to `index.html`. Even though the app would work, the HTTP response would still be 404.

So I've tried `react-snap` to prerender my routes. It works for all routes except those behind authentication. For example, if a user goes to `/dashboard`, he will be redirected to `/login`. So then `react-snap` renders the `/login` route for the `/dashboard` route.

Is there a better way to be doing this? Thanks in advance.

**edit**: I'm using react-router for client side routing. The prerendering of pages is just so that S3 does not use the error page for the other routes on initial load.

Comment: I am using [react-router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router#readme)

Comment: I'm using react router too. but that doesn't solve the issue of initial loading working but with HTTP status 404 on a S3